# What does "こっち" mean in this sentence?

Tags: sentence

From "Run with the Wind" episode 1:

> なんでタバコなんすか。臭い、臭い、臭い。これ訴えたら百ゼロでこっちっすよ

The person who said this is a law student. Not sure if it helps but I just want to add that. I can only parse the sentence as "If I sue this, ... 100% ..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

こっち in this context refers to this (suing) side, i.e., the claimant. こっちっす implies he will win the case. In other words, 勝つのは is the implied subject.

This 百ゼロ means "100:0", i.e., "absolutely". 百[対]【たい】ゼロ is the standard way to say this, but in colloquial speech, 対 may be simply omitted (e.g., 水と砂糖を七三【ななさん】で混ぜる = Mix water and sugar at 7:3).

> これ訴えたら百ゼロでこっちっすよ
> If I sued this, I'll win by a ratio of 100:0.